# ¿Como leer correctamente un archivo ignorando ciertas palabras en Java?

Tags: java, archivo

Como puedo leer este archivo .txt, ignorando las palabras:

- Id libro:
- Titulo:
- Editorial:
- Lista de autores:

  e ignorar la linea completa:

  - "-------Texto: ".

Imagen de referencia:
[image: Imagen de referencia]

Utilicé este código para leer el de autores y funciona muy bien:

```
//Metodo para leer el archivo de autores
public void leerArchivoAutores() throws  IOException{
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(ArchivoAutores);//ArchivoAutores es de tipo File ya definido
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String linea = "";        
    while ((linea= bufReader.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] datosAutores = linea.split("--");
        //En la clase Globales es donde tengo el Arraylist de listaAutores
        Globales.listaAutores.add(new Autor(Integer.parseInt(datosAutores[0]), datosAutores[1], datosAutores[2]));            
    }
}
```

[image: imagen de autres]

La pregunta sería 
 **¿Cómo puedo modificar este método para poder leer un archivo como el de la primera imagen?**

Comment: Hola Reyes_98, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, es recomendable agregues lo que has intentado!, saludos!

Comment: A qué clase le vas a agregar los datos que leas? Estoy en ello :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos, Reyes_98.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un método donde leas tu archivo y pasarle en un arreglo esas cadenas de texto que deberían ser ignoradas, de esta manera, al momento de leer tu archivo si se encuentra alguna referencia de ese texto, se omite.

Por ejemplo:

```
/**
 * Este método te permite leer cualquier archivo y omitir las palabras
 * ingresadas en el arreglo
 *
 * @param file el archivo que será leído
 * @param textos_a_ignorar el arreglo de textos que se ignorarán
 * @throws FileNotFoundException en caso de que el archivo no se encuentre
 * @throws IOException si ocurre una excepción mientras se leía el archivo
 */
public void leerArchivo(File file, String[] textos_a_ignorar) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // Se lee la siguiente línea del archivo
        for (String texto : textos_a_ignorar) { // recorremos el arreglo de textos que deben ser omitos
            if (line.contains(texto)) { // si se encuentra alguna coincidencia
                line = line.replace(texto, ""); // se reemplaza por un espacio en blanco
            }
        }

        if (!line.isEmpty()) { // después de realizar la búsqueda, si la línea no está en blanco
            System.out.println(line); // se imprime la línea
        }
    }

    // no olvides cerrar
    br.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

De esta manera, al momento de llamar tu archivo, haríamos esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        // Se crea un arreglo de cadenas de texto con las palabras que deben ser omitidas
        String[] textos_a_ignorar = new String[]{"Id libro:", "Titulo:", "Editorial:", "Lista de autores:", "-------Texto:"};

        // Se llama el método de la clase Main, se envía el archivo y el arreglo
        new Main().leerLibro(new File("Cien años de soledad.txt"), textos_a_ignorar);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // si el archivo no se encuentra
        System.out.println("El libro no existe");
    } catch (IOException e) { // si ocurre un error leyendo el archivo
        System.out.println("Ocurrió un error leyendo el archivo: " + e);
    }
}
```

El código anterior es sólo un ejemplo, podrías cambiar el acceso del método `leerArchivo` por estático, para no tener que crear la instancia de `Main` (en mi caso así se llama mi clase).

Y de la manera anterior, simplemente tendrías que ingresar en un arreglo las palabras y textos que deberían ser omitidos del archivo que lees.

---

Por otro lado, si lo único que piensas leer son esos libros, podrías crear un método específico para los libros, en tu caso, observemos el libro que nos presentas:

```
Id libro:7
Titulo:Cien años de soledad
Editorial:Harper, Jonathan Cape
Lista de autores:
Gabriel García Márquez--Colombia
-------Texto:
Muchos años despues, frente al pelotón de fusilamiento, el coronel Aureliano Buendía había de recordar aquella tarde remota en que su padre lo llevó a conocer el hielo. Macondo era entonces una aldea deveinte casas de barro y cañabrava construidas a la orilla de un río de...
```

**Si todos los libros** que piensas agregar o manipular en tu programa tienen la misma estructura y definición (todos tienen un `id`, un `titulo`, una `editorial`, una `lista de autores` y el `texto` del libro), eso nos serviría como patrón para crear una clase `Libro` y por ende, también sabríamos qué palabras omitir de los archivos que leemos, por ejemplo:

```
public class Libro {

    private String id;
    private String titulo;
    private String editorial; // Editorial debería ser otra clase más, esto es un ejemplo
    private String autor; // Autor debería ser otra clase más, esto es un ejemplo
    private String texto;

    // Constructores, getters y setters...
}
```

Y así, podríamos definir un método específico para los libros:

```
/**
 * Este método te permite leer un archivo libro
 *
 * @param file el archivo con la información libro
 * @return retorna un arreglo con los datos importantes del libro
 * @throws FileNotFoundException si el archivo no se encuentra
 * @throws IOException si ocurre una excepción leyendo el archivo
 */
public String[] leerLibro(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // este arreglo nos permitirá almacenar la información de la clase Libro para utilizarla después
    // se define con 5 espacios por nuestras variables que son 5 (id, titulo, editorial, autor y texto)
    String[] datos = new String[5];

    // es el mismo arreglo de antes, pero no hace falta definirlo en el método debido al patrón que mencionamos
    String[] textos_a_ignorar = new String[]{"Id libro:", "Titulo:", "Editorial:", "Lista de autores:", "-------Texto:"};

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line;
    int aux = 0; // el auxiliar nos permite recorrer los campos del arreglo datos para almacenar las líneas
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        for (String texto : textos_a_ignorar) {
            if (line.contains(texto)) {
                line = line.replace(texto, "");
            }
        }

        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            datos[aux++] = line; // almacenamos la linea en el arreglo
        }
    }

    // no olvides cerrar
    br.close();
    fr.close();


    /*
    También podríamos retornar la clase libro y no solo los datos:
    Para esto, deberías cambiar el tipo de dato que retorna este método
    (String[]) por Libro

    Libro libro = new Libro();
    libro.setID(datos[0]);
    libro.setTitulo(datos[1]);
    libro.setEditorial(datos[2]);
    libro.setAutor(datos[3]);
    libro.setTexto(datos[4]);

    return libro;
    */

    return datos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el siguiente código hace lo que quieres. Fíjate que lo que hago con cada dato recogido es imprimirlo con `System.out.println();`. Lo que quieras hacer con esto queda a tu elección:

```
public static void leerDatos() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(archivoDatos);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String linea;
    String dato;
    while ((linea = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] li = linea.split(":");
        if (linea.contains(":") && l.length > 1) {
            dato = li[1].trim();
            System.out.println(dato);
        } else if (!linea.contains(":")) {
            dato = linea;
            System.out.println(dato);
        }
    }
    bufReader.close();
}
```

Comment: estas llamando dos veces a `linea.split(":")` deberías de pasarlo a una variable para optimizar

Comment: De acuerdo. En un minuto :-)

Comment: en el momento en que llega al `while` borras el valor de la variable `línea`, considera no inicializarla

Comment: para evitar el close o dejar algún flujo abierto deberías de usar try con recursos para que lo haga por tí

Comment: Nunca he utilizado `try with resources`, pero si me editas la respuesta no hay problema!

Comment: Afortunadamente en este sitio puedes preguntar acerca de conceptos y sus ventajas, te recomiendo hacer una pregunta con un título similar a "¿Qué es un try con recursos y que ventajas tiene?"

Comment: también creo que `linea.contains(":")` busca una subcadena y si usas en su lugar un `linea.indexOf(':') != -1` podrías hacer más rápido tu método

Comment: Edita la respuesta con las sugerencias que haces y las aprobaré en seguida, lo digo en serio

Comment: Es tu código, las optimizaciones solo las indico por si alguien necesitara una versión optimizada

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75026/discussion-between-victor-herasme-perez-and-ruslan-lopez-carro).

Answer (score 1):

Quizás te sea más fácil darle otro formato al archivo si puedes. Por ejemplo puedes añadir un espacio y una coma al final de cada atributo. Seria asi:

```
ID Libro: id ,
Titulo: nombre del libro ,
Editorial: nombre de la editorial ,
Autores:  
Autor 1, Autor2 ,
-------Texto:
texto.
```

Una vez que el archivo tenga ese formato lo puedes juntar todo en una String y separarla por " ," y luego ":" para separar las parejas y añadirlas a una lista, por ejemplo Map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> atributos = leerAtributos("so.txt");

    //puedes acceder a cada entrada por su nombre usando el metodo get()
    System.out.println(atributos.get("Titulo"));
    System.out.println(atributos.get("Editorial"));

    //o poner todos los valores en tu lisa usando el metodo values()
    List<String> tuLista = new ArrayList<>();
    tuLista.addAll(atributos.values());
    System.out.println(tuLista);
}

static Map<String, String> leerAtributos(String rutaDelArchivo){
    Path archivo = Paths.get(rutaDelArchivo);//nombre del archivo a leer
    try{
        //Esto pondra el archivo entero en una sola String
        //y luego se puede usar split para separar los atributos
        String[] parejas = Files.lines(archivo)
                                .reduce(String::concat)
                                .get().split(" ,");

        //Esto separa cada lina y crea un Map con cada pareja 
        Map<String, String> valores = Arrays.stream(parejas)
                                             .map(e -> e.split(":"))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0]  , e -> e[1]));  
        return valores;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    return null;
}
```

Pasando la ruta del archivo a la función leerAtributos() te devolverá un Map que permite acceder a cada atributo por el nombre que le hayas puesto a la izquierda del ':' o a todos los atributos a la vez si usas la función values().

para usar este código hay que importar:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.nio.file.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código también podría servir para leer ese archivo:

```
public String[] leerLibro(int indiceLibro) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // se define con 5 espacios por nuestras variables que son 5 (id, titulo, editorial, autor ,texto)
    String[] datosDelLibro = new String[5];

    //Texto que vamos a ignorar del arreglo
    String[] texto_A_Ignorar = new String[]{"Id libro:", "Titulo:", "Editorial:", "Lista de autores:", "-------Texto:"};       

    FileReader reader = new FileReader(ArchivosDeLibros.get(indiceLibro));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String line;
    int numDeLinea=1; //contador de lineas recorridas 
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {            
        if (numDeLinea==1) {//Id:
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                line = line.replace(texto_A_Ignorar[0], "");
                datosDelLibro[0] = line;                    
            }
        }
        if (numDeLinea==2) {//Título:
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                line = line.replace(texto_A_Ignorar[1], "");
                datosDelLibro[1] = line;                    
            }
        }
        if (numDeLinea==3) {//Editorial:
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                line = line.replace(texto_A_Ignorar[2], "");
                datosDelLibro[2] = line;                    
            }
        }
        if (numDeLinea==4) {//Lista de Autores:
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                line = line.replace(texto_A_Ignorar[3], "");
                datosDelLibro[3] = line;                    
            }
        }
        if (numDeLinea>5) {//Texto del libro
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {                    
                datosDelLibro[4] += line;
            }
        }
        numDeLinea++;//cambio de linea
    }//fin for


    bufferedReader.close();
    reader.close();       


    return  datosDelLibro;//(id, titulo, editorial, autor ,texto)
}
```

Eso si deje a todos los autores en una sola linea

```
Id libro:1
Titulo:Cien años de soledad
Editorial:Harper, Jonathan Cape
Lista de autores:Gabriel García Márquez--Colombia,
-------Texto: 
Muchos años después, frente al pelotón de fusilamiento, el coronel Aureliano 
Buendía había de recordar aquella tarde remota en que su padre lo llevó a 
conocer el hielo”. Con estas palabras empieza una novela ya legendaria en 
los anales de la literatura universal, una de las aventuras literarias más 
fascinantes del ...
```

Aunque sin problema yo creo que para leer los autores se puede usar el método .split(",")